# How to make a sql query for which we need 1 column to be null after the first occurence, if the other column value gets repeated?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose we have 4 columns from a table invoice_details

```
Customer Order ||   invoice number.    ||   Work Order     ||    Invoice Amount
    O2911               9011                   20113                  5000
    O2911               9012                   20114                  6000
    O2912               9012                   20114                  6000
    O2913               9013                   20115                  7000
    O2914               9014                   20116                  6000
```

Output should be like

```
Customer Order ||   invoice number.    ||   Work Order     ||    Invoice Amount
    O2911         9011        20113        5000
    O2911         9012        20114        6000
    O2912         9012        20114          -
    O2913         9013        20115        7000
    O2914         9014        20116        6000
```

as the invoice number (9012) is repeated, its invoice amount too (i.e 6000), so I want only the first invoice amount for the invoice no and rest all should be null as shown above.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: oracle sql.hope that answers your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be easy if your RDBMS can support Window Function,

```
SELECT  "CustomerOrder", 
        "Invoicenumber", 
        "WorkOrder", 
        CASE WHEN rn = 1 
             THEN CAST("InvoiceAmount" AS VARCHAR(20))
             ELSE '-'
        END "InvoiceAmount"
FROM
        (
            SELECT  "CustomerOrder", "Invoicenumber", "WorkOrder", 
                    "InvoiceAmount",
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Invoicenumber" 
                                        ORDER BY "CustomerOrder") rn
            FROM    TableName
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4793/4)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════╗
║ CUSTOMERORDER ║ INVOICENUMBER ║ WORKORDER ║ INVOICEAMOUNT ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ O2911         ║          9011 ║     20113 ║ 5000          ║
║ O2911         ║          9012 ║     20114 ║ 6000          ║
║ O2912         ║          9012 ║     20114 ║ -             ║
║ O2913         ║          9013 ║     20115 ║ 7000          ║
║ O2914         ║          9014 ║     20116 ║ 6000          ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply bud.. but wanted to know,what if there are many columns like 20 or more cols in a table,do i need to list to list all,coz my logic is dependent on 1 col i.e invoice_no and changes are made in other col invoice_amount depending on no of occurences of invoice_no.   here above we have listed all columns of a table,but in case of many cols or in case of join of many tables,it will be like a big clunky sql...please help JW

Comment: hmmmm i dont know whether i put up my point or not properly,like if my table had customerorder,invoice,number,workorder,invoiceamount,part_info,inventory_value,no_of_parts_remaining,line_no,site,company,billing_address.....etc etc...so in your written query solution,we would have to write many cols name like select "customerorder","customerorder","workorder","invoiceno","invoiceamount".......blah blah............from (select...blah blah col name.....from.....)....so what suggestion you give so that it becomes concise

Comment: actually there is no problem if you have big chunky sql. the point of my delete comment is to make a dynamic sql so you will not need to manually define the column names. it will build on its own since it will be searching for available columns on the tables.

Comment: JW somehow your previous comment got deleted,i dont know how :(....btw thanks for your suggestion,hmmm just wanted to ask so we dont have any way so that the select clause which you showed  cant be done in a similar way like "select * ,case(on something) from (one more select clause)"(pseudo code),is there  a way by which we can put "*" apart from dynamic sql you saying..thanks JW

Comment: please if you can leme know,what are your thoughts on above...just curious in which we need to display all columns by putting * and then apply some logic by case in a select query,is that possible....Please leme know

Comment: i tried to implement on below query(oracle SQL),
`SELECT
--all V1 cols
rn,
CASE
WHEN rn = 1
THEN CAST(invoice_amount AS VARCHAR(20))
ELSE '-'
END invoice_amount,
FROM
(SELECT V2.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY invoice_no
ORDER BY invoice_no) rn
FROM IFS_IO.OWS_SALES_DETAILS_V V2
where V2.invoice_no='0009463'
)V1,
IFS4.CUSTOMER_ORDER_ADDRESS COA
WHERE
COA.ORDER_NO = V1.CO_NO
AND TRUNC(V1.INVOICE_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('&INVOICE_DATE_FROM','MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('&INVOICE_DATE_THRU','MM/DD/YYYY')
AND V1.SITE=NVL('&SITE',V1.SITE)
AND V1.CUSTOMER_ID=NVL('&CUSTOMER_ID',V1.CUSTOMER_ID)
`

Comment: i am getting the min value of rn as 2 and for occurences of invoice_no ,am getting the rn value as 2,3,4...so on...
the output(partial output with imp cols)   
  
INVOICE_NO RN INVOICE_AMOUNT  
  
9459       2     -  
    
9460          2     -  
  
9461          2     -  

9462          2     -  
  
9463          2     -  
  
9463          3     -  
  
9463          4     -  
  
9463          5     -

Comment: am not able to put my output table in here somehow,please if you can provide me with email id so that i can forward it to you